# Android NDK | How to debugging app startup or suspend app until debugger connected

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, dbg

During investigation crash of  my cocos2d-x app I faced with problem that debugger not stops in AppDelegate.cpp class at all.

My assumption is: debugger could not connect before time when this code has been executed.

Is my assumption correct? Is any workaround there?

Comment: see [Debugging App Startup with VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/documentation/appstartup).

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for the link. But I see three problems here: 1. `VisualGDB` haven't plugin for `Eclipse`; 2. `VisualGDB` doesn't support `OSX`; 3. `VisualGDB` isn't free;

Comment: You are right. 3 times ;) That's why I didn't post this as an answer. Probably, you can reproduce their logic for your private solution. It would be great if you share it with us, when ready.

Comment: One simple approach is to throw in a `sleep` call that stalls app startup at the appropriate point for a few seconds.  Just long enough to let the debugger get set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden) you can add call `sleep` (or `usleep`) function. In case `cocos2d-x` you should put it in beginning of `void Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz, jint w, jint h)` function

```
void Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv* env, 
                                                       jobject thiz, 
                                                       jint w, 
                                                       jint h)
{
#if COCOS2D_DEBUG    
    sleep(30);
#endif
    ...
}
```

Also you should not forget to include `<unistd.h>` in case `usleep`